# Links and breaks not showing in front-end of Blog-post

Tags: wordpress, post, blogs, wysiwyg

When adding breaks and links inside my blost-post the markup doesn't show in the front-end of the website. I would expect that the links would be clickable, but they aren't. The HTML output doesn't show any  markup at all.

The blog post uses the standerd WYSIWYG editor of Wordpress 4.9.9

The code inside the editor:

```
In de winter maanden organiseren wij ook een aantal pizza- party- 
aanschuiftafels, binnen in onze stubli. De volgende data 2019 kun je nog 
mee eten:  vrijdag 25 januari, vrijdag 8 maart en vrijdag 29 maart.

Aanvang: 18.30u, eerder komen borrelen? Altijd gezellig! Vanaf 19 april 
bakken wij weer iedere vrijdag pizza's, buiten onder de grote luifel.

Je kunt je opgeven via de mail (noodzakelijk):<a 
href="mailto:%20info@bijonsingroesbeek.nl"> info@bijonsingroesbeek.nl</a>
```

The HTML output:

```
In de winter maanden organiseren wij ook een aantal pizza- party- 
aanschuiftafels, binnen in onze stubli. De volgende data 2019 kun je nog 
mee eten:  vrijdag 25 januari, vrijdag 8 maart en vrijdag 29 maart. 
Aanvang: 18.30u, eerder komen borrelen? Altijd gezellig! Vanaf 19 april 
bakken wij weer iedere vrijdag pizza’s, buiten onder de grote luifel. Je 
kunt je opgeven via de mail (noodzakelijk): info@bijonsingroesbeek.nl
```

Template code:

```
<?php if ( $portfolio_count == 1 || ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 2 && (!$fullwidth && ($portfolio_count+1) % 2 == 0) ) || ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 3 && (($portfolio_count+1) % 2 == 0) ) ) {
                    $et_open_row = true; ?>
                    <div class="et_pt_portfolio_row clearfix">
                <?php } ?>

                        <div class="et_pt_portfolio_item">

                            <?php { ?><h2 class="et_pt_portfolio_title"><?php echo esc_html( $et_portfolio_title ); ?></h2>
                            <?php } ?>
                                <div class="et_pt_portfolio_entry<?php if ( $height == $et_portrait_height ) echo ' et_portrait_layout'; ?>">

                                    <div class="et_pt_portfolio_image<?php if ( '' != $et_videolink || '' != $et_custom_embed_video ) echo ' et_video'; ?>">
                                    <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, ''); ?>
                                    <span class="et_pt_portfolio_overlay"></span>

                                    <a class="et_portfolio_zoom_icon fancybox" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"<?php if ( '' == $et_videolink && '' == $et_custom_embed_video ) echo ' rel="portfolio"'; ?> href="<?php if ( '' != $et_videolink || '' != $et_custom_embed_video ) echo esc_url( '#' . $et_video_id ); else echo($thumbnail['fullpath']); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Zoom in','Chameleon'); ?></a>
                                    <a class="et_portfolio_more_icon" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Read more','Chameleon'); ?></a>
                                </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_image -->
                            </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_entry -->
                            <?php if ($et_ptemplate_showdesc) { ?>
                                <div id="bijonshome_p"><p><?php truncate_post(500); ?></p></div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_item -->
```

I would like the have the links and breaks visable in the HTML output, is this possible with the standard editor? Or should a plugin be installed like ACF to make this possible? Any idea's, fixed or suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue, in the template the function  was used. This is a kind of excerpt which doesn't shows any links or HTML markup. I changed

```
<?php truncate_post(500); ?> with -> <?php the_content(); ?>,
```

and it works perfect now :)